# FosUserBundle / Symfony 4 - The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony4

My Symfony4 app is working fine in dev environment but not in production, i can't login (using FosUserBundle). After enabling debug and profiler toolbar in production (beacause it doesn't write any log) i've found the error

> The class 'App\Entity\FintelUtility\User\User' was not found in the
>   chain configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Model

The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces

I've cleared the cache and i've checked mapping info of doctrine

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=prod
 Found 2 mapped entities:
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
wwwfintel@fnt-srvweb01:~/s4fgel$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=dev                             
 Found 5 mapped entities:
 [OK]   App\Entity\FintelUtility\QuoteOfTheDay
 [OK]   App\Entity\FintelUtility\User\Group
 [OK]   App\Entity\FintelUtility\User\User
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
```

I don't know how to map those three entities that are missing.

**config/packages/doctrine.yaml**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: mssql_fgel_utility
        connections:
            mssql_fgel_utility:
                driver:   ~
                driver_class: "%fgelutil_database_driver_class%"
                host:     "%fgelutil_database_host%"
                dbname:   "%fgelutil_database_name%"
                user:     "%fgelutil_database_user%"
                password: "%fgelutil_database_password%"
        types:
            datetime_key: 'App\Type\DateTimeKeyType'
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: mssql_fgel_utility
        entity_managers:
            #################################
            # Update schema only with this em
            #################################
            mssql_fgel_utility:
                connection: mssql_fgel_utility
                mappings:
                    FintelUtility:
                        type:     "annotation"    
                        # The directory for entity (relative to bundle path)
                        dir:      '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/FintelUtility'   
                        prefix:   'App\Entity\FintelUtility'
                        is_bundle: false
```

Ther's no config/packages/dev/doctrine.yaml but prod
**config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.result_cache_provider

services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

I've tried also php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug but it didn't help

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I've changed "mssql_fgel_utility" entity manager to "default" and it worked for prod but **then it doesn't work for dev**

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: mssql_fgel_utility
    entity_managers:
        #################################
        # Update schema only with this em
        #################################
        # THIS WAS WRONG EVEN IF I DON'T KNOW WHY
        # mssql_fgel_utility:
        #################################
        default: #changed to this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed "mssql_fgel_utility" entity manager to "default" and it worked

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        #################################
        # Update schema only with this em
        #################################
        # THIS WAS WRONG EVEN IF I DON'T KNOW WHY
        # mssql_fgel_utility:
        #################################
        default: #changed to this
```

Comment: If someone knows why it acts so i will appreciate the explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I've cleared the cache and i've checked mapping info of doctrine

Is it the Symfony cache or Doctrine cache? if it's not the Doctrine cache, clear it and try the command `php bin/console do:sc:va` to check the mapping and check if the database is in sync with the mapping and make the `php bin/console do:sc:up --force --env=prod` in the case it's not in sync.

Comment: I've cleared both cache, sorry i didn't explained. DB is not out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `"mssql_fgel_utility"` entity manager to `"default"` and delete `"default_entity_manager: mssql_fgel_utility"` and it will work for `dev` and `prod`.

Comment: Why that ? Need explanation.

Comment: Overriding doctrine `default_entity_manager` in config_prod.yml do the job : 
   `orm:
        default_entity_manager: mssql_fgel_utility
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        #result_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu`